# Carry ownProps deep react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to gain access to params in ownProps. Is there a way to solve this?

Current structure is

```
const Router = () => (
  <router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/signup' component={Signup} />
      <Route path='/browse' component={Browse}/>
      <Route path='/detail/:id' component={Detail} />
    </Switch>
  </router>
)
```

i want ownProps to pass on to these pages in Detail

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Info />
        <Message/>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to gain access to id in mapStatetoProps

Comment: Where is your mapStateToProps code ?

Comment: you dont have access to the id in a route inside map state to props.. its a prop that is injected to the component via this.props.params. if you want to do something with it just use the props in componentWillMount

Comment: function mapStateToProps({posts}, ownProps){
    console.log('>>>>>>>> post_show State to props', ownProps);
    return { post : posts[ownProps.match.params.id]};
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPost, deletePost })(PostsShow);

Answer (score 0):

After messing around I found a way which is that I passed the required information as props to nested components.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Info idInfo={this.props}/>
        <Message idInfo={this.props}/>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

after this I got information in ownProps.